# how i can use another symbol in kucoin websocket other than XBTUSDM?

Tags: python, websocket, cryptocurrency, kucoin

I use kucoin websocket to connect to kucoin exchange and receive real-time data
https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-futures-python-sdk

In order to receive the data of different currencies, the following address must be used (according to what is in the documentation related to kucoin transactions)
**/contractMarket/level2:XBTUSDM**

But when I change the symbol, for example, **ADAUSDM** web socket does not work for me
And it gives me the following message

`websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: sent 1000 (OK); then received 1000 (OK)`

I would be grateful if someone could guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ADAUSDTM instead of ADAUSDM. It worked for me.
For other currencies, use currency name + USDTM.